# Springboot webserver running on Windows Server 2016 / AWS not working

Tags: java, windows, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, windows-server-2016

I am having difficulties getting visibility to my cloud server (Windows Server 2016 OS on AWS) from external computer.

1. I am taking the default springboot from https://start.spring.io/
   Using Java 8 and packaged as Jar.
2. I use "gradle bootJar" to make the jar file.
3. I boot up a windows 2016 server on AWS/EC2.
4. I put the file on the cloud server.
5. IIS is disabled.
6. I install java 8 sdk
7. I run the jar file in cmd with "java -jar -Dserver.port=80 myapp.jar"
8. I open up HTTP and all traffic to and from the server in AWS.

Now locally(RDP into my cloud computer), I see the app fine at http://localhost:80.
But remotely (eg. at work), I cannot reach the server location of http://"my servers public ipaddress":80.

Note: Running the app as a service with Winsw did not help my problem.

I also noticed that running IIS, I am able to see the default IIS screen from remote computers.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the Spring Boot embedded server is not listening only on localhost (127.0.0.1)? You may need to set `server.address` to `0.0.0.0` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: this does not appear to be working:                java -jar -Dserver.port=80 -Dserver.address=0.0.0.0 "C:\a.jar"

Comment: Did you verify that it's listening on 0.0.0.0:80?

Comment: I believe yes. If I do http:// localhost/   I can view the app locally.

Comment: That verifies the port but not the IP. Maybe you can use `netstat` or something to be sure.

Comment: Active Connections
...
  TCP    [::1]:80               EC2AMAZ-7GR6VG7:61450  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:61450            EC2AMAZ-7GR6VG7:http   ESTABLISHED

Comment: Have you allowed 0.0.0.0:80 on AWS Security Group for incoming traffic?

Comment: I used netstat -a and I see TCP 0.0.0.0:80 and [::]:80 on another line

Comment: I have a line for inbound on HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0 and HTTP
TCP
80
::/0

Comment: "locally" -> You mean RDP to AWS server and type http://localhost:80? or from your laptop/desktop?

Comment: Locally, I mean RDP into my AWS server and using chrome to localhost:80 into my app just fine.

Comment: Could it be that Windows is blocking the port 80?

Comment: Thanks, I turned off the firewall and now it's working. If you write that as an answer I will mark it as answered

Comment: Nice. Added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Windows firewall is not blocking the port 80.

Comment: Thank you so much!